# How do I resolve a "does not have sufficient permissions i.e. not writable and readable" error in Apache NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi's fundamental GetFile function seems to fall over with a permissions error:
[image: screenshot of nifi Permissions error]

In Dushyant's [tutorial/example](https://youtu.be/rgRY1soeTQs?t=2636) there don't seem to be any permission errors with GetFile, even with the configuration "Keep Source File" set to False.

Relevant [docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/) don't appear to cover this error.

As advised [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/84338/getfile-nifi-does-not-have-sufficient-permissions.html), I've tried replacing Getfile with ListFile/FetchFile in a number of combinations but still encounter the same error.

Comment: I don't see a screenshot of the error

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean - there’s a screen shot in the OP but perhaps it’s not loading in your browser? In any case I’ve solved the error and will now post the solution here. Thanks for reminding me to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was `chmod 777 opt/input /opt/output`

i.e. loosen permissions on the directory being read from, and the directory being written to.

chmod 755 (default setting for newly created directories) is not enough, and leads to errors. Switching the directories’ permissions from 777 back to 755 causes the errors to return.

Comment: Further suggestions for resolving this error, made by Dushyant in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgRY1soeTQs&lc=UgyAwJtz2xFQIANtA4d4AaABAg.8w6nQ4nirin8wBq_EpW75Y) YouTube comment.